# Java URLrewrite Filter - Passing parameter

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I need a rule for my urlrewrite.xml

I need to redirect this:

```
www.mysite.com/test-news.php?id=23
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/news?id=23
```

This is my actual filter:

```
<rule match-type="regex">
 <from>^/test-news.php(.*)?$</from>
 <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/news?$1</to>
</rule>
```

But doesn't work.. Don't recognize `?id=`

Thanks

Luis

Comment: make sure you are including use-query-string="true" in your urlrewrite tag.

Answer (score 1):

If using version 4, use the qsappend attribute on **`<to>`** tag as below (if using version 4)

```
<rule match-type="regex">
<from>^/test-news.php$</from>
<to type="redirect" qsappend="true">/news</to>
</rule>
```

If using version 3, Use **`use-query-string`** attribute on the root tag **`<urlrewrite>`**

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
......some lines of ther rules if any-----
<rule match-type="regex">
    <from>^/test-news.php$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/news</to>
</rule>
```